# GraceNote rhythm API with Pygn

Tags: gracenote, pygn

The following works and retrurns a list of semmingly random tracks which GraceNote thinks are similar to Bowe's work:

`radioPlayList = pygn.createRadio(GRACENOTE_CLIENT_ID, GRACENOTE_USER_ID, artist='Bowie', count='3');`

However, I would **strongly** prefer to pass a genre, rather than an atrist - I just can't figure our how.

This `radioPlayList = pygn.createRadio(GRACENOTE_CLIENT_ID, GRACENOTE_USER_ID, genre='38', count='3');`  returns `<RESPONSES>\n <RESPONSE STATUS="NO_MATCH">\n </RESPONSE>\n</RESPONSES>` which lead me to beleive that Genre should not just be a simple number.

And trying to give the genre as a text, `radioPlayList = pygn.createRadio(GRACENOTE_CLIENT_ID, GRACENOTE_USER_ID, genre='Oldies', count='3');` gives `<RESPONSES>\n  <MESSAGE>GCSP: RADIOCREATE error: [8] radio: Invalid attribute seed.</MESSAGE>\n <RESPONSE STATUS="ERROR">\n </RESPONSE>\n</RESPONSES>\n` so that is obviously not the way to do it.

QUESTION: how can I pass a Genre (only) and get a radio playlist in return?

The only [Pygn docuemntation](https://github.com/cweichen/pygn) which I can find does not help.  I am hoping that @cweichen will se thsi question & help me. Does anyone else know how?

---

[Update] Looking in the code of Pygn's [test.py](https://github.com/cweichen/pygn/blob/master/test.py), I see

`# Example how to create a radio playlist by genre classical music
result = pygn.createRadio(clientID, userID, genre='36061', popularity ='1000', similarity = '1000')
print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4))`

Question: where do I get a list of those genre values?   The file [readme.md](https://github.com/cweichen/pygn/blob/master/README.md) says `genre: a genre ID from the genres below`, but here is no list below.

Comment: BTW you may get better results for the artist station if you use the full name "David Bowie"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of genres (or moods, or eras) you need to make a call to the "fieldvalues" API - this isn't in pygn yet, but you can see how to do it here:

https://developer.gracenote.com/rhythm-api#attribute-station

This call will give you the list of supported genres:

https://cXXXXXXX.web.cddbp.net/webapi/json/1.0/radio/fieldvalues?fieldname=RADIOGENRE&client=CLIENT_ID&user=USER_ID

You can then use the returned ID's with pygn.createRadio()

Comment: +1 Thanks, Wei Chen, I _knew_ you woudl come through for me :-)   I will code it later & award the answer when I have proven it. Who knows, I might even fork Pygn and some ListGenres/ListMoosd/ListEra functions (unless, of course, you want to take time out of your busy schedule to do it yourself ;-)